# NPM: exists-sync is deprecated

Tags: node.js, git, ember.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I am receiving the following warning:

> npm WARN deprecated exists-sync@0.0.4: Please replace with usage of
>   fs.existsSync

Is there any NPM command that I need to do in order to get rid of this warning? I checked GitHub and  understand that this project is for checking if a file exists (see link below). Currently, my project does not have any dependency on this function. So, I am just trying to find out if there is anything I need to do?

https://github.com/ember-cli/exists-sync

**Update**

I followed Leesei's advice and got the result below, which I think it means to say that `exists-sync` still exists under `ember-maybe-import-regenerator@0.1.6`. Am I correct? Is it safe to uninstall `exists-sync`?

[image]

Comment: If your project does not use this module, then just remove that module from your local repository with `npm uninstall exists-sync`.

Comment: if your project isn't using directly `exists-sync` you should check what module using it by doing: `npm ls exists-sync` and update parent module in the dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

If your project isn't using that dependency, another dependency probably is. You can try to update your dependencies. Maybe the package authors replaced the deprecated usage in a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this: `npm dedupe && npm prune` to clean unused dependencies.

If the `exists-sync` module remains then `npm ls` to see which package depends on it and try to update/inform the author of that package.

Answer (score 1):

If you `npm install broccoli-funnel@2.0.1` (which is the latest release), that should resolve those notices. Also, `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i` likely will also force npm to install the latest versions of that package.

Honestly, deprecation warnings like this aren't an something to worry about, and are an artifact of dependency updates and eventually all packages in the ecosystem get the latest deps.

Comment: The first command resulted in an error that broccoli-funnel@2.01 could not be found (or something to that effect - I am not at my computer right now). However, with that being said, I am now enduring a substantial slow down in VS Code (it takes 10 minutes to do anything: build a route; start the server; etc) and I am attempting to resolve that. I will circle back to this once I solve my computer slowness.

Comment: It’s 2.0.1. Typo on my part